# calling a method from inside InterfaceBuilder declared UIView subclass

Tags: objective-c, xcode, methods

So i'm having trouble with accessing a method inside of a UISubview class. I'm not initializing through code but I've added a UIView and have set the class to `IVVerticalProgress`.

but when i try to call

`[_weakIBOutlet setProgressValue:50];`

Nothing happens and i get no print. However if i init the object it works perfectly fine. But doesnt update the view.

Any help here? :-)

**Header**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class IVVerticalProgress;

IB_DESIGNABLE

@interface IVVerticalProgress : UIView {
    UIView *gauge;
    CGFloat initialHeight;
}

@property (nonatomic) IBInspectable CGFloat cornerRadius, borderWidth;
@property (nonatomic) IBInspectable UIColor *fillColor, *borderColor;
@property (nonatomic) IBInspectable double animationDuration;

-(void)setProgressValue:(CGFloat)value;

@end
```

**Body**

```
#import "IVVerticalProgress.h"

@implementation IVVerticalProgress

-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    self.layer.backgroundColor = self.fillColor.CGColor;
    self.layer.borderColor = self.borderColor.CGColor;
    self.layer.borderWidth = self.borderWidth;
    self.layer.cornerRadius = self.cornerRadius;
    self.clipsToBounds = YES;

    gauge = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,rect.size.width,0)];
    [gauge setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [self addSubview:gauge];
}

- (id)sharedInit {
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    initialHeight = self.layer.frame.size.height;
    return self;
}


- (id)initWithFrame: (CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame: frame];
    if (self) {
        self = [self sharedInit];
    }
    return self;
}

-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        self = [self sharedInit];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)setProgressValue:(CGFloat)value {
    if (value < 0)
        value = 0;

    if (value > 100)
        value = 100;

    CGFloat percentageHeight = (initialHeight / 100) * value;
    [gauge setFrame:CGRectMake(gauge.frame.origin.x,
                               gauge.frame.origin.y,
                               gauge.frame.size.width,
                               percentageHeight)];
    NSLog(@"%f",value);
}

@end
```

Comment: did you check again its calling and also printing value for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In both cases it will work well, if you using drag and drop in storyboard or using initWithframe, as you have implemented both initWithCoder and  initWithFrame and your setProgressValue is independent of how you are creating your view

here is the link to the project using your IVVerticalProgress you can check is have used both programmatically as well as storyboard and both working perfectly.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [_temp setProgressValue:50];

    IVVerticalProgress *fromCode = [[IVVerticalProgress alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20,300, 200, 200)];
    [fromCode setFillColor:UIColor.blueColor];
    [fromCode setBorderColor:UIColor.cyanColor];
    [fromCode setCornerRadius:10];
    [fromCode setBorderWidth:10];
    [fromCode setProgressValue:100];
    [self.view addSubview:fromCode];
}

OutPut 
2018-04-10 19:55:24.482438+0530 testView[4011:134919] 50.000000
2018-04-10 19:55:24.482755+0530 testView[4011:134919] 100.000000
```

[image: OutPut in Simulator]

If still not working for you let us know :-)

Comment: Okay, so after trying all this. I realized my IBOutlets weren't connected properly. So thanks for the extensive explanation and thank you for the time. I'll accept your answer as the correct one since you've led me in the right way! :)